# Efficiently access most recently accessed MongoDB entries?

Tags: mongodb

I'm making a service with similar requirements to a URL shortener; I need to store a bunch of unique hashes and their corresponding strings. The tricky part is that I also need to order them by access date so that I can retrieve the last 10 accessed entries (and the next 10 after that, etc.)

Everything that I've come up with so far is grossly inefficient. What's the best way to store a queue like this?

Comment: there is no way to find recent accessed data so make something like "recentAccess" or something and update it everytime you call the URI then you can do something like find().sort({recentAccess : 1})

Comment: Can you show us what you came up with so we don't recommend the same thing you already tried? Sharing your research helps everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution: Add an `accessed_at` field which you update when the url is accessed. Index it, then you can find URLs sorted by the accessed_at field.

You could alternately use a capped collection that holds recently accessed URLs; each time a URL is accessed, insert it into the capped collection. That will give you a rolling window of the most recent accesses. It won't deduplicate, though, so if a URL is particularly popular, it will show up in that list multiple times.

Comment: accessing and updating can be done in one query by using [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).